# C++ read select parts of std::string

Tags: c++, string

I have been trying to extract only "Apple" from the string below ie. between "," and "/". Is there a way to extract the string between the delimters? Currently, all of the string after the "," is extracted.

```
std::string test = "Hello World, Apple/Banana";

std::size_t found;                  
found = test.find(",");

std::string str3 = test.substr(found); 
std::cout << str3 << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

One step at a time. First, extract the part after the comma. Then extract the part before the following slash.

Alternatively, `substr()` also takes an optional 2nd parameter, the maximum number of characters to extract, instead of extracting everything that's left of the string. So, if you compute how many characters you want to extract, you can also do it in a single `substr()` call.

Comment: `.find()` takes an optional starting position. You can use that to find the position of the slash after the comma, then subtract them to get the length of the substring.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is finding where the substring "Apple" begins.  You can use find() for that.  It returns the location of the first character of the substring.  You can then use the std::string constructor to pass in the original string with start and stop locations.

References 
[String find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/),
[String constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

```
std::string extractedString = std::string(test, test.find("Apple"), sizeof("Apple") - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second argument of `substr` to find the length of the extraction

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    string test = "Hello World, Apple/Banana";
    size_t f1 = test.find(',');
    size_t f2 = test.find('/');
    string extracted = test.substr(f1, f2 - f1);
}
```

This will output `, Apple` when using VC2013.  If you change `f1` to `size_t f1 = test.find(',') + 2;` it will output `Apple`.